# void* type cast breaks strict -aliasing?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays, strict-aliasing

I wrote a dynamic array like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t len;
} __dynarray_header;

void* dynarray_new() {
    __dynarray_header* header = malloc(sizeof(__dynarray_header));
    header->capacity = 0;
    header->len = 0;
    return header + 1;
}
```

The dynamic array can be accessed with a `[]` operation. When resizing, I can use `__dynarray_header*)array - 1` to retrieve capacity and length information.

The idea works in small tests. However, GCC warns about breaking strict-aliasing.

I've also found some larger projects segfault without the `-fno-strict-aliasing` compiler option (with `-O3` optimization).

I know what strict-aliasing is, and why my code breaks strict-aliasing.

My question is: Is there a better way to implement a dynamic array supporting both the `[]` operation and dynamic resizing than the one I showed above?

Extra:

A demo program using this dynamic array:

```
int* arr = dynarray_new();
arr = dynarray_resize(sizeof(int) * 2);
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr = dynarray_resize(sizeof(int) * 4);
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
dynarray_free(arr);
```

Comment: With zero space overhead?  You're squarely in territory that Dennis Ritchie (the 'R' in K&R) called "unwarranted chumminess with the implementation."

Comment: Isn't that what flexible array members are for?

Comment: @CarlNorum:  Good point.  Is this C89 or C99?

Comment: @CarlNorum, I want a "dynamic" array, like std::vector in C++.

Comment: @JoeZ, For example an int array: `int* arr = dynarray_new()`. after that we can resize arr and use `arr[i]` to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main optimization afforded by `-fstrict-aliasing` is that references to `foo *` can be arbitrarily moved past references to `bar *` in most circumstances.  The segfaults you see are likely due to a reference getting moved past a `free` type operation somewhere.

While this feels a little dirty, you may be able to make it work under C89 by adding a union of prospective array element types into your structure, such as:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t len;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
        my_type mt;
        etc e;
        /* add additional types here. */
    } array_head;
} __dynarray_header;
```

Then, instead of returning `header + 1`, return `(void *)&(header->array_head)`.

Now, even with strict aliasing, the compiler is more likely to consider a pointer to `__dynarray_header` to possibly alias a pointer to anything in that union, unless the pointers are also `restrict`-qualified.  (I'm assuming for your use case, they are not, at least in the contexts that trigger seg-faults.)

Still... as Dennis Ritchie said, it seems like "unwarranted chumminess with the implementation."  Or, in other words, a hack.  Good luck!

(Edit:  As Carl above reminded me, in C99 you can use flexible array members.  I haven't used them, simply because C99 support doesn't seem to be the default in the C compilers I use.  Here's IBM's reference: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzarg%2Fflexible.htm )

Comment: but we still have to use `(__dynarray_header*)array - 1` to retrieve the header?

Answer (score 1):

The technique that the C standard foresees for such a thing are flexible arrays, as was already mentionned:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t len;
    unsigned char data[];
} dynarray_header;
```

If you allocate (or re-allocate) such a `struct` with enough space you may access the `data` element like any `unsigned char` array. `char` types may alias any other data type, so you wouldn't have problems with that.

If your compiler doesn't support flexible arrays, just put a `[1]` in there for `data`.

BTW, names starting with underscores are reserved in file scope, you are not supposed to use these.